# Why do brushless motors heat up?

Tags: temperature, electric-engine

I would like to know what makes a brushless motor heat up. I'm aware of the problems generating the high temperature such as wire contact problems or overloaded motors. I want to know what makes a normal motor in normal conditions warm up. Is it related to the Joule effect?

Comment: Because copper has resistance and you have current flowing thru it

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance

Comment: Thanks, Koyovis already answered me perfectly, much appreciate to all of you.

Comment: "*Koyovis already answered me perfectly*": It may deserve an upvote.

Comment: as i'm a new member i can't upvote it, i specified it to be what i was looking for, and i hope so you guys stop with this way of communication, i'm here to ask a question and you make it seem like a pathetic idea. just stop with over reacting to everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The motor is converting electrical energy in mechanical energy, and unfortunately all energy conversions lose some energy to heat. [This site](https://www.groschopp.com/blog/efficiency-and-losses-in-electric-motors/) states the cause of the heat losses as:

- Friction losses due to bearings etc.
- Windage losses due to air resistance.
- Iron losses caused by magnetic paths of the motor (hysteresis losses and eddy current losses).
- Ohmic losses from current flow.
- Stray losses: other